# Terraform template_file resource with for_each variables

Tags: powershell, dictionary, foreach, terraform

I'm trying to write a user data template file with a map containing user group access but cannot find any examples of this being done anywhere and not sure how to go about it. Is it possible?

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

Example of terraform.tfvars:

```
group_membership = {
  backup_folder_access = [
    "fred",
    "alice"
  ],
  full_folder_access = [
    "greg"
  ]
}
```

Example of userdata.ps1.tpl:

```
foreach ($group in ${group_membership}){
  New-LocalGroup -Name $group.key
  foreach ($user in ${group}.value){
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group -Member $user
}
```

Example of template_file resource:

```
data "template_file" "userdata" {
  template = file("${path.module}/src/userdata.ps1.tpl")
  vars = {
    group_membership = "${var.group_membership}"
}
```

This is clearly incorrect, anyone know how this should look?

Comment: What wrong with the code? What errors do you get?

Comment: As it is, I get: "Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "group_membership": string required."

Comment: start by passing your variable as a map instead of a string: `group_membership = ${var.group_membership}`

Comment: @ESG I think the issue is the opposite here, the variable needs to be a string but I'm passing it a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days you should use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile), not `template_file`. Then it would be:

your template:

```
%{for group, value in group_membership ~}
  New-LocalGroup -Name ${group}
  %{for user in value ~}
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group ${group} -Member ${user}
  %{ endfor ~}    
%{ endfor ~}
```

and `templatefile`:

```
locals {
  userdata = templatefile("${path.module}/src/userdata.ps1.tpl", {
                  group_membership = var.group_membership
             })  
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin - you are a very wise man! I can confirm this works.